# Share point closed web parts are not showing up

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have few surveys which are already created on share point. However they are not showing up the export to spread sheet option in the actions tab.

So after checking this link http://deinfotech.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/sharepoint-2007-surveymissing-export-to.html I wanted to follow its instruction.

But on my share point 2010 there is no "Closed Web parts" under share point web parts category list. Funny enough there is no "Advanced Web Part Gallery options" as well. see the [screenshot](http://wasgamuwaholidays.com/test/sharepoint.png).

Can someone please help me out here. I'm stuck for last 3 days on this and I'm very new to share point as well. What's wrong with my share point? Even if i used the share point designer i can't find the "Closed Web parts" section to re-drag them again.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Internet Explorer/Chrome/Firefox - Its same for every browser. I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get to closed webpart by appending contens=1 to the query string of the url.
ex: http://site/Pages/default.aspx?contents=1